# Azure CLI - Check if Azure frontend port already exists

Tags: azure-devops, azure-cli

I have a CLI script that I'm using to deploy an Azure App gateway and various things

As part of that script I am executing

```
az network application-gateway frontend-port create
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName \
        --gateway-name $appGatewayName \
        --name 'creditassessment' \
        --port 443
```

but it errors saying it already exists

How can I check for it's existence first?

Comment: You could use az network application-gateway frontend-port list to list the detailed info about it, then check if it already exists: `az network application-gateway frontend-port list -g MyResourceGroup --gateway-name MyAppGateway` https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/frontend-port?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_application_gateway_frontend_port_list-examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if Azure frontend port already exists, you can list frontend ports with [az network application-gateway frontend-port list](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/frontend-port?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_application_gateway_frontend_port_list) or get the details of a frontend port with [az network application-gateway frontend-port show](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/network/application-gateway/frontend-port?view=azure-cli-latest#az_network_application_gateway_frontend_port_show).

For example, to check if the port is used within PowerShell.

```
$frontendportCheck = az network application-gateway frontend-port list -g $resourceGroupName --gateway-name $appGatewayName --query "[?port=='$frontendPort']" | ConvertFrom-Json
$frontendportExists = $frontendportCheck.Length -gt 0
if (!$frontendportExists) {
    az network application-gateway frontend-port create `
        --resource-group $resourceGroupName `
        --gateway-name $appGatewayName `
        --name $frontendportname `
        --port $frontendPort
}
```